# Combo box styling to show rating and description WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, styles

I'm not very good with styling in WPF, so I thought that I would ask here and see if anyone can help.

I have a combo box which is bound to a view model that has a rating and description, when I hover my mouse over a item the item changes to show the rating and description for that item.

This works ok however because some of the descriptions are really big and there is no word wrapping it just looks ugly.

I don't know if this possible but what I am after is the list of ratings on one side and a description box on the other, but I only want the description box to show the current highlighted one.

Something like this:

[alt text http://img94.imageshack.us/img94/6787/comboidea.png](http://img94.imageshack.us/img94/6787/comboidea.png)

Can anyone help me with this or at least point me in the right direction to get started.

Thanks,
Nathan

Comment: I guess you can't make the descriptions shorter?

Comment: I can't really because I'm dealing with condition rating some of them get pretty full on.

Answer (score 0):

You could edit a copy of the data template  (The internet will tell you how to easily do this with Blend).  In that data template, add an area to the right.

It can be another panel, you can extend the grid to the right, or add horizontal extender...however you want to do it.

Then you can add two bindings to whatever you add to the right.  One binding will be for the description you want to display (bind it to some textbox).  And the second will be to the new panel's visibility.  Set it to collapse it when the description is too long.

I would be more descriptive, but I'm guessing that's all you really needed.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you don't want to use a ToolTip for this?

**Edit**

I just realized what it is that you're actually asking for.  You want some way of displaying properties of the item that is the current selection in the `ComboBox's` list.

You can't do this with the `ComboBox` as such, because the `SelectedItem` property it exposes doesn't change while the user is navigating through the pulled-down list, it only changes when the user makes a selection.

But if you edit the `ComboBox`'s control template (and here Blend is useful), you'll have access to the pulled-down list's `ItemsControl` itself (I forget what kind of `ItemsControl`, I haven't looked at the template in a while).  And you'll be able to access  *its* `SelectedItem` property.

It might actually be worth building a `UserControl` based on the `ComboBox`, adding a `CurrentItem` dependency property to it, and binding that to the `ItemsControl`'s `SelectedItem` property.  Once you do this, you have a `ComboBox` that looks just like an ordinary `ComboBox`, except it exposes a `CurrentItem` property you can bind another control to.

P.S. I haven't actually done this particular thing, so I don't know what kind of gotchas you'll encounter when you try it.

Comment: mainly because not everyone will use a mouse to select the item, and I still what the description to be show if they just open the box for a quick look at the rating.

Answer (score 0):

Use a DataTemplate to completely redefine the line:

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="superRow" >
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <StackPanel.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5,2,0,0"/>
                </Style>
            </StackPanel.Resources>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Rating}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=RatingDescription}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Then in the combobox:

```
 <ComboBox ItemTemplate="{StaticResource superRow}" />
```

(other needed comboBox options missed for simplicity)